# Code Navigation for JavaScript in VSCode: Navigating to external class methods

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, webstorm, code-navigation

I am facing a bit difficulty in navigation in VSCode while using JavaScript. Using <kbd>F12</kbd>, I am able to navigate to internal class methods but suppose I have a call to some external classes' method, using a global object, then <kbd>F12</kbd> or "Go to definition" or anything doesn't seem to work.

This feature is available in WebStorm but can't figure out why can't I do this in VSCode. Please, if someone could help me out.

Comment: Do you have the definition in a different file?

Comment: Yes, the other file has a class and it's his method that I'm calling from some file. Then I have an object of that class. Can't go to the method definition from the call (which is in some other file).

Comment: How are you importing that file? Are you just including it in your HTML next to the other file?

Comment: Working in cocos2d-js, so they are kind of like globally accessible objects.